# Spark use inherited scala functions (Java/SparkSQL)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use a inherited Scala function ( StuctType.diff() ) and im getting a *NoSuchMethodError*.

---

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.diff(Lscala/collection/GenSeq;)Lscala/collection/Seq;
    at TableNode.neighborNode(SparkSQLTest.java:112)
    at SparkSQLTest.main(SparkSQLTest.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)*

---

The code looks like:

```
public StructType foo(DataFrame df){
    StructField sf = this.schema.diff(df.schema()).last();
    StructType schema_tmp = new StructType().add(sf);
    return schema_tmp;
}
```

Someone has any ideas? I'm using Spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10

Comment: Can you execute `sc.version` to see what Spark version you use? You can use `spark-shell` to check it out.

Comment: Hi, I executed. I'm using Spark 1.6.2

Comment: Can you show the entire code? Can you show how you define the dependencies? Are you using sbt?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm using Spark 2.0 and StructType method is supported.Please have a look at the code snippet below I hope its helpful :

> val schema = new StructType(Array(
>       StructField("STORE_ID", StringType,true),
>       StructField("SALE_DATE", DateType,true)))